# Is it "nobody's business but the Turks" or "nobody's business but the Turks'"?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Is it *nobody's business but the Turks* (it's nobody's business, except that it is the business of the Turks); or is it *nobody's business but the Turks'* (it's nobody's business, except that it is the Turks' business)? Should there be an apostrophe or not?

The phrase, for context, is from the song "Constantinople" by They Might Be Giants.

> Istanbul was Constantinople.
> Now it's Istanbul, not Constantinople.
> Been a long time gone, oh Constantinople.
> Why did Constantinople get the works?
> That's nobody's business but the Turks

Comment: You don't *pronounce* the possessive ***'s*** attached to plural ***Turks***, but conceptually it must be present. Nobody ever says *It's nobody's business but **me***, for example - that's always *...but **mine***.  In your context, the "bare" apostrophe should be written ***after*** the word ***Turks***, because *nobody's business but the **Turk's*** would imply it only concerns one context-specific Turk, rather than all Turks collectively.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I like the "nobody's business but me/nobody's business but mine" reasoning. Will you post an answer with that explanation?

Comment: I do not find @RMac's answer satisfying, so I will not accept it as it stands, but I would accept an answer that presented your reasoning.

Comment: @Hamnerite My answer does present reasoning. I can't see why you don't think so. Please elaborate on your question if there's some other rationale you'd like to see.

Comment: Yes, it presents reasoning. But it does not present the reasoning presented by FumbleFingers in their first comment. And I favour that explanation, so I've decided arbitrarily that I shan't accept any answer that doesn't explain things in those terms.

Answer (score 7):

It's nobody's business but the Turks'.

"Turks" is a word used to refer to the main ethnic group of Turkey and to the people belonging to that group. Because it is plural and because because the "business" belongs presumably to all of them (Istanbul, formerly Constantinople, is in present day Turkey), you use the possessive plural variant.